# How do I find intersection of these 2 (trig) curves?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

$1)$ $x=\sin(y)$ and $x=\dfrac{2}{\pi}y$

Setting them equal, I get  $\sin(y) = \dfrac{2}{\pi}y$

Where do you go from here?  Does $\sin^{-1}$ come into play?

$2)$ While I'm at it, how do you find the intersection of $y=\sin(x)$ and $y=\csc(x)$ ?

Thanks, I really do appreciate the knowledge shared by posters on this forum.

Answer (score 1):

$\sin y=\frac2\pi y$ is a transcendental equation so it won't probably have many "nice" solutions and then you'll have to approximate them or, perhaps, prove they exist.

Yet the coefficient $\;\frac2\pi\;$ should make you "suspect" something, and you can check  we have two solutions $\;y=\pm\frac\pi2\;$ here, besides the trivial one $\;y=0\;$ , for example.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Since DonAntonio already answered the second question, I shall just try to help you for the first.

What is the definition of Csc(x) ? Does Csc(x) relate in any manner to Sin(x) or to Cos(x) or Tan(x) ?

I am sure you can take from here.

Comment: Reciprocal function.  Csc(x) = 1/Sin(x)  They will only be equal when they are equal to 1 ?  Sin(90)=1.    $Csc(90)=\frac{1}{sin(90)}=\frac{1}{1}=1$   Yea?

Comment: Not exactly but very close ! Replace Csc(x) by its reciprocal, reduce to the same denominator and then ...

Comment: Ok, let me try what you're saying.  $csc(x)=\frac{1}{sin(x)}$.   Reduce to the same denominator as sin(x)?  If so, $\frac{1}{sin(x)}=sin(x)$ which means $\frac{sin^2(x)}{sin(x)}=\frac{1}{sin(x)}$ which means $sin^2(x)=1$ which means $sin(x)=1$ which means $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: What's the best way to format the above?  It would be nice to put each step on a new line.  And can I use an arrow for the repeated "which means..."?

Comment: @JackOfAll. Sin(x)^2=1 implies Sin(x)=1 and Sin(x)=-1. Then the solutions are (2n+1) Pi/2.